# overlapping subviews in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I am stuck with this. I will explain with my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


   NSNumber *cellno=[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:indexPath.row];
   imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 13, 15,18)];
   imgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"lock.png"];

   tickView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 13, 15,18)];
   tickView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"];

   switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel.text=@"apples";
        if ([appDelegate.connected containsObject:cellno]) { //condition
            [cell.contentView addSubview:tickView];
        }else{
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
        }
        break;
    }
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    return cell;
}
```

During the first time the tableview is loaded the 'imgView' subview is added to the cells content view and the after some operation the 'if' condition is satisfied and the 'tickView' is added.

The problem is, the oldview is not hidden or removed and hence both the images appear.

Help would be greatly appreciated

[image: Both the tickview and imgView appears]

Comment: You have to be careful in adding and removing, since cell is reused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating your imgView and tickView views in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, create them when you create the cell and reuse them with the cell.  Then you can do this:

```
...

if (cell == nil) {
   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
   imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 13, 15,18)];
   imgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"lock.png"];

   tickView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 13, 15,18)];
   tickView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"];
}

...


if ([appDelegate.connected containsObject:cellno]) { //condition
    [imgView removeFromSuperview];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:tickView];
}else{
    [tickView removeFromSuperview];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
}
```

Comment: Sorry..I dont follow. What do you mean when you say creating the views when i create the cell ?

Comment: Right now you are alloc/init-ing a new UIImageView and new UIImage every time cellForRowAtIndexPath is called.  Presumably you are not alloc/init-ing a new UITableViewCell every time (you have elided part of your code, so I can't tell for sure).  Is this correct?